# git checkout -B without reset or alternatives?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-checkout

I want to use a command that will do:

1. Create a new branch if it doesn't exist.
2. Checkout branch if it exists without any modification to it.

Currently used `git checkout -B branchname` violates the second requirement because it resets the branch to `HEAD` of starting point if branch exists. Do you know any flags to `checkout` / workarounds / another commands that will satisfy both requirements?

Comment: You can probably sort it out with a shell pipeline (or better a shell function) executed as a Git alias.

Comment: Seems like the only option... `git checkout branchname` and if it fails, `git checkout -b branchname`, as torek recommended in his answer.

Comment: Indeed. `git checkout branchname -- 2>/dev/null || git checkout -b branchname`.

Answer (score 4):

There's no one single Git command that will do this.

The command sequence I recommend using is:

```
git checkout <name>
```

followed by, *if* that fails:

```
git checkout -b <name> [<starting-point>]
```

*or* (depending on what behavior you want):

```
git checkout [-b <name>] --track <remote-tracking-name>
```

where each item in angle brackets represents something you replace (e.g., `<name>` might be `feature/fast`) and each item in square brackets represents something that is optional.

The main issue here is this:

- **If you are creating a new branch name**, you *must* choose which commit this new branch name will identify.  You choose a specific starting point by supplying a `<starting-point>` argument; if you fail to name a starting-point, Git will assume you want `HEAD` as the starting point.

  You *may* also choose whether the new branch should have an upstream set: that's what the `--track` is for.  However, note that in some cases, `--track` is implied automatically.
- **If you are using an existing branch name**, you—per your statement above—do not want to *change* which commit it will identify.  (You do not, at this time, have the option of setting / changing the upstream for the existing branch, so that particular question drops out of the picture.)

Let's now touch on all the side issues that happen here.

#### With `-b`, `git checkout` always wants to create a new branch

The `-b` and/or `--track` flag tells `git checkout` that it should both create the new branch and then switch to it.  If the switching-to will or does fail, it should roll back the entire operation and not create the new branch after all.  So here there *is* a starting-point.  The starting-point *may* be `HEAD`.  Because the branch is *new*, it does not yet have an upstream, but you can tell `git checkout` to *set* an upstream, using `--track`: the argument to `--track` is the name of the upstream (which should be either a local branch name, or a remote-tracking name such as `origin/master`).

If you supply the `-b` flag, you also supply the new branch name, and that is therefore the new branch's name.  If you omit the `-b` flag, you must have provided `--track` and a remote-tracking name: in that case, the branch's name is the name produced by removing the remote-tracking part, e.g., `origin/feature` becomes `feature`, so `git checkout --track origin/feature` means the same thing as `git checkout -b feature --track origin/feature`.

If you supply a starting-point, Git will need to check out that specific commit.  The starting-point name can be a remote-tracking name (such as `origin/master` or `origin/feature`), or a commit hash ID, or anything else that identifies a commit.  In most cases, supplying a remote-tracking name as a starting-point is equivalent to supplying the `--track` argument as well, so if you *don't* want to set an upstream, add `--no-track`.  See [the `git checkout` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) for a complete description.

#### Without `-b`, `git checkout` still sometimes creates a new branch

When you leave out `-b`, `git checkout name` will first test to see if *name* matches some existing branch.  If so, the decoding part of the operation is done: Git now tries to check out that particular commit (identified by that branch) and if that succeeds, attaches your `HEAD` *to* that branch, so that you're now on the branch.

But you can write, e.g.:

```
git checkout feat/ure
```

when you do not *have* a branch named `feat/ure`.  In this case, Git will enumerate *all* your remote-tracking names, such as `origin/master`, `upstream/master`, and so on.  If *exactly one* matches `feat/ure` after stripping off the remote part, Git assumes that you *meant* to write:

```
git checkout --track origin/feat/ure
```

(or whatever the name is with the remote still in it).  Hence this will *create* `feat/ure`, pointing to the *same* commit as `origin/feat/ure`, with `origin/feat/ure` as the upstream setting of the new branch `feat/ure`.

If no `feat/ure` exists and either there are either no, or too many (two or more) remote-tracking `feat/ure` style names—e.g., both `origin/feat/ure` and `upstream/feat/ure` exist—this `git checkout` will simply fail, and now you must resort to one or more of `-b` and/or `--track`.

#### Another alternative

If you don't like these alternatives, it *is* possible to test whether a branch name exists.  To do so, ask `git rev-parse` to translate the name, with `refs/heads/` inserted in front of it:

```
git rev-parse --quiet --verify refs/heads/feat/ure
```

If this succeeds, it prints out the hash ID to which `refs/heads/feat/ure` resolves, and exits with a zero status.  The printed hash ID is the tip of the `feat/ure` branch, which therefore exists.  If this fails, it prints nothing (`--quiet --verify`) and exits with a nonzero status, so `feat/ure` does not exist.  You can now safely ask to *create* `feat/ure`—that is, provided that no one else has snuck in to your repository and created `feat/ure` while you were looking at the exit status and determining that `feat/ure` did not exist (but now does).

In a shell script, this becomes:

```
name=feat/ure
git rev-parse --quiet --verify refs/heads/$name >/dev/null && exists=true || exists=false
if $exists; then git checkout $name; else git checkout -b $name ...additional arguments; fi
```

and of course you can turn this script into a shell alias or actual shell script, calling it whatever you like.  Add sufficient argument parsing and error handling to taste.