# PowerShell - git checkout -B without reset or alternatives?

Tags: windows, git, powershell

Related to this question: [git checkout -B without reset or alternatives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55622319/git-checkout-b-without-reset-or-alternatives)

I want to change branches, but create the branch if it doesn't exist. `-B` doesn't work, as I have un-pushed commits on the branches and don't want them to be reset.

How would you write this: `git checkout branchname -- 2>/dev/null || git checkout -b branchname` in powershell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent of this shell command...

```
git checkout branchname -- 2>/dev/null || git checkout -b branchname
```

...in PowerShell would be this:

```bsh
$branchname = "your-branch"
git checkout $branchname 2>&1 | Out-Null
if (-not $?) {
    git checkout -b $branchname
}
```

It uses the [$?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7#section-1) automatic variable, to determine if the last command succeeded. Also, error stream [redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-7#powershell-redirection-operators) and [Out-Null](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/out-null?view=powershell-7).

Note that in PowerShell 7 (Core), `||` and `&&` are also available, called [pipeline chain operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipeline_chain_operators?view=powershell-7).

```bsh
git checkout $branchname || git checkout -b $branchname
```